# How to save form-data that contains array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman, multipartform-data, mongoose-schema

I have a model containing an array like this:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
path: {
    type: String
},
list: [{
    element1: {
        type: Number
    },
    element2: {
        type: Number
    }
}]})
```

In the route file:

```
const prescription = new Prescription({
    ...req.body,
    path: req.file.path
})
```

What I want to use POST request to get this model data via **form-data**. And that looks like:

[image]

Saved that model using:

```
prescription.save()
```

Unfortunately what I get response (It doesn't contain the array elements):

[image]

If I log in console with:

```
console.log(req.body)
```

It shows:

[image]

And for:

```
console.log(req.body.list)
```

It returns `undefined`.

**Please let me know how to get that response with array elements successfully?**

Comment: Looks like your problem is parsing the form data, not getting the response. I'd look into something like 'busboy' to parse the incoming form data. Also, note you have a type in `element1`

Comment: Noted:  if I follow my way without any array in the form-data (only some single key-values) it gives a clear response.